# haskell translate string to Int

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to make a function that translate for example the string B1 C2 into two int tuples using the findLetter function defined below. B = 2 and C = 3. It will also reverse the tuple order. Hence B1 C5 == ((1,2),(5,3)).

```
accoList = [("A", "1"),("B", "2"),("C", "3"),("D", "4"),("E", "5"),
("F", "6"),("G", "7"),("H", "8")]

findLetter :: String -> String
findLetter c = findLetter' c accoList
where findLetter' c ((x,y):xs) = if x == c then y else findLetter' c xs
    findLetter' c [] = undefined

--userToMove1 :: String -> ((Int, Int),(Int, Int))
userToMove1 s = userToMove' $ take 5 s
   where userToMove' (a:b:c:d:e:xs) =  ((read b , (read (findLetter a))),((read e), (read (findLetter d))))
```

When I run this code I get exceptions like non-exhaustive pattern and when I don't comment out `--userToMove1 :: String -> ((Int, Int),(Int, Int))`, the program gets full of errors. I don't know how to fix it :(

Comment: Your `findLetter'` function is equivalent to the `lookup` function in the `Prelude`. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: You might find it easier to split `"B1 C5"` into a list of strings `["B1", "C5"]` first (keeping in mind that a `String` is really a `[Char]`, and `"B1"` is just `['B', '1']`). The built-in `words` function will do that for you

Comment: The main problem I see is that you're trying to `read` a `Char` in the case of `b` and `d`, while `read` only accepts a `String` argument. (Likewise you're feeding the wrong type to `findLetter`)

Comment: And regarding `findLettet`, besides using `lookup`, you don't need your `accoList` at all if you use the `ord` function from `Data.Char` (you'll have to subtract a constant from its output, but that's all, apart from using `show` if you insist on the output being a `String`).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you confuse `Char`s with `String`s.

When you pattern-match a `String` to `(a:b:c:d:e:xs)`, all the elements except for `xs` are actually `Char`s and not `String` -- that's why `xs` has an 's' at the end, remember Strings are lists.

So the findLetter should have signature `findLetter :: Char -> String` as it takes a `Char` from `userToMove1` and returns a String from `accoList`

Also it doesn't really make sense for findLetter to return a String, you can either read the string in `findLetter` itself or even better have an Int in the tuple. This is how I would write this:

```
accoList = [('A', 1),('B', 2),('C', 3),('D', 4),('E', 5),('F', 6),('G', 7),('H', 8)]

findLetter :: Char -> Int
findLetter c = findLetter' c accoList
  where findLetter' c ((x,y):xs)
    | x == c    = y
    | otherwise = findLetter' c xs


userToMove1 :: String -> ((Int, Int),(Int, Int))
userToMove1 s = userToMove' $ take 5 s
  where userToMove' (a:b:c:d:e:[]) =  ((read b , findLetter a),(read e, findLetter d))
```

Finally, I'd like to say that this code looks weird, and there's probably a better way of achieving whatever you want to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern match `(a:b:c:d:e:xs)` takes the first 5 characters of the string; each is of type `Char` and not of type `String`, which is a synonym for `[Char]`. Because the type doesn't match, it can't find appropriate functions for `read` or `findLetter`.

You can fix the immediate problem by converting the characters back to strings, thus:

```
where userToMove' (a:b:c:d:e:xs) =  ((read [b] , (read (findLetter [a]))),((read [e]), (read (findLetter [d]))))
```

Also, you could redefine `findLetter` as:

```
findLetter c = fromJust $ lookup c accoList
```

Answer (score 0):

In ghci you can use `:t userToMove1` to inspect the inferred type of your function. In your case this returns:

```
*Main> :t userToMove1
userToMove1
  :: (Read t, Read t1, Read t2, Read t3) =>
     [String] -> ((t3, t2), (t1, t))
```

ghci inferred that your input parameter is a List of Strings instead of just a String, like you want it to be.

Why does this happen?

In `userToMove1` you pattern match on a List and feed the elements of the List to your `findLetter` function. Those expect Strings, therefore the matched elements (a,b,c,d,e) must be Strings, therefore `s` must be a List of Strings. 
If you rewrite `accoList` and `findLetter` to accept Chars instead, ghci would infer `s` to be a List of Chars which is a String. Then your original typsignature would work.

Assuming this is for a chess game, using Chars instead of Strings would be preferrable anyway, as positions can only be single letters.